# Netgear WNA3100 wifi dongle not recognized

Tags: usb, netgear

I have the latest version of Ubuntu, but it will not recognize my wireless adapter (Netgear WNA3100).  How do I get it to search for (any) USB device and how do I get it to use it to gain access to the internet?

Comment: There appears to be good info for setting it up on `ndiswrapper`'s SourceForge page: http://ndiswrapper.sourceforge.net/wiki/index.php/Netgear_WNA3100

Answer (score 1):

Just used ndiswrapper to install a WN3100-100ENS on Lubuntu 16.04.1.  Almost easily, it got to the state where the driver was installed and present.

But it took much longer for me to get connected to my wireless router (with wpa2 security).  So, I added wpa_gui, which seemed to get things rolling. But, still push button WPA didn't work, many manual attempts failed, mostly with password rejection.  In the end, I needed "linssid" which reported that my modem expected WPA2 and TKIP -- so in wpa_gui, I used these parameters to add the "network" (SSID, etc).  It connected immediately.  (Before trying this, I had expected that the required connection parameters would be discovered automatically)

Actually, I just noticed that there is a status tab in wpa_gui, and you can scan for networks there. Also, the network notification applet in the task bar, seems to be unaware that I do have a wi-fi connection.  You also have to run wpa_gui with "sudo" in a terminal window (even though it shows up as a menu item).  On my Lubuntu system, if you use the network notification interface on the task bar, you will continously get asked for the password. Also, once you connect through wpa_gui, this task bar interface thinks that wifi is disconnected.  The only interface I have found which works is wpa encryption is wpa_gui.